# Installed test APK does not appear on device's main screen

Tags: android, robotium, android-testing

I installed an instrumentation test APK from Eclipse(Run->Run As Android application) on device as the log shows below.

[2013-08-08 22:14:13 - SettingsTests] /SettingsTests/bin/SettingsTests.apk installed on device

However, on the home screen of the device, somehow the test APK does not show. In Settings->Application Manager, the list shows the test apk correctly.

Any idea what's going on?

---

The android system info shows:
Source:/data/app/PACKAGE.test.test-1.apk
data:/data/app/PACKAGE.test.test

---

Here's the test apk's manifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="PACKAGE.test.test"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="17" />

<instrumentation
    android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
    android:targetPackage="my.package" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 4):

Only the activity defined in manifest like below will be shown. You must define at least one activty like that.

```
    <activity
        android:name="YourActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to install doesn't have an activity defined in the manifest.

As per the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

```
An activity is that implements part of the application's visual user interface.
All activities must be represented by <activity> elements in the manifest file.
Any that are not declared there will not be seen by the system and will never be run.
```

You can refer the [document](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html) so as to have an idea how activity works

Answer (score 1):

It's quite normal behavior, as you don't have any activity in your instrumentation package. Didn't you mean to run it as Android JUnit Test?